# How do I print a half pyramid with numbers and stars together?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, nested-loops

I'm trying to print a half pyramid with numbers and stars together and the output must be like this:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1
2 * * * * 2 
3 * * * 3
4 * * 4
5 * 5
6 6
7
```

Here is the code that I've done so far:

```java
public class numberplsustar {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int rows = 7, i, j, num;
        for (i = rows; i >= 1; i--) {
            for (j = 1; j <= i; ++j) {
                if (i >= 3 && i <= 6) {
                    System.out.print("* ");
                } else
                    System.out.print(i + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the output:

```
7 7 7 7 7 7 7 
* * * * * * 
* * * * * 
* * * * 
* * * 
2 2 
1
```

Comment: Kobe if you think one of the answeres were helpful, mark it as accepted

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you don't check for the first character and the last character to print the values. Also start printing from `rows`: 7.

- You should start printing from `1` (`j=1`), than increment the value on each time `j++`.
- You should check for which value to be printed on each step:

  `(i == rows || i == 2 || temp == 1) ? j : "*"`

  prints `j` (number) :

  - `i == rows` : for the first row (`1 1 1 1 1 1 1`)
  - `i == 2` : for the row before the last one (`6 6`)
  - `temp == 1` : for the numbers at the end of rows

  otherwise prints `*`

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int rows = 7;

    for (int i = rows, j = 1; i > 0; i--, j++) {
        System.out.print(j);
        for (int temp = i - 1; temp > 0; temp--) {
            System.out.print(" " + ((i == rows || i == 2 || temp == 1) ? j : "*"));
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1
2 * * * * 2
3 * * * 3
4 * * 4
5 * 5
6 6
7
```

PS: In Java the first letter of class names should be capitalized according to naming conventions.

Answer (score 0):

just print every characterindividualy and if its on the outline you print the number

```
public class piramid {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 7;
        for (int i=1; i<n; i++) {
            for (int x=n; x>i; x--) {
                if (i == 1 || x == n || x==i+1) {
                    System.out.print(i);
                }
                else {
                    System.out.print("*");
                }
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }

}
```

this code outputs this

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 
2 * * * 2 
3 * * 3 
4 * 4 
5 5 
6
```

in response to your comment:
this would work:

```
public class piramid {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 7;
        for (int i=1; i<n; i++) {
            for (int x=0; x<i; x++) {
                if (i == n-1 || x == 0|| x == i-1) {
                    System.out.print(i);
                }
                else {
                    System.out.print("*");
                }
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }

}
```

and the output is

```
1 
2 2 
3 * 3 
4 * * 4 
5 * * * 5 
6 6 6 6 6 6
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution

- Check if `i == 1`(first) row -> print `i`
- Check if **j is at the edge** `j==i || j == range`  -> print `i`
- else print `"*"`

---

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int range = 7;
    for(int i = 1; i <= range; i++){
        for(int j = range; j >= i ; j--){
         if(i == 1){
            System.out.print(i);
         }else if(j == range || j == i){
            System.out.print(i); 
         }else{
             System.out.print("*");
         }
         
                        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

#### Outsputs

```
  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
  2 * * * * 2 
  3 * * * 3 
  4 * * 4 
  5 * 5 
  6 6 
  7
```

Answer (score 0):

To print a triangle in some corner of a 2d array, you can use two nested *for loops* (or streams) and two nested *conditional statements* (or ternary operators). Your code might look something like this:

```java
int m = 7;
IntStream.range(0, m)
    .mapToObj(i -> IntStream.range(0, m)
        // 'i' - row, 'j' - column
        .mapToObj(j ->
            // triangle corner:
            // upper left: 'i + j < m'
            // lower right: 'i + j >= m - 1'
            // lower left: 'i >= j'
            // upper right: 'i <= j'
            i + j >= m - 1 ?
                // triangle boundaries:
                // top: 'i == 0'
                // bottom: 'i == m - 1'
                // left: 'j == 0'
                // right: 'j == m - 1'
                // primary diagonal: 'i == j'
                // secondary diagonal: 'i + j == m - 1'
                i == m - 1 || j == m - 1 || i + j == m - 1 ?
                    // row number
                    (i + 1) + " "
                    // otherwise asterisk
                    : "* "
                // otherwise whitespace
                : "  ")
        // collect into one line
        .collect(Collectors.joining()).stripTrailing())
    // print line by line
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
            1
          2 2
        3 * 3
      4 * * 4
    5 * * * 5
  6 * * * * 6
7 7 7 7 7 7 7
```

---

```java
int m = 7;
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    String row = "";
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
        if (i <= j) {
            if (i == 0 || j == m - 1 || i == j) {
                row += (i + 1) + " ";
            } else {
                row += "* ";
            }
        } else {
            row += "  ";
        }
    }
    System.out.println(row.stripTrailing());
}
```

Output:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1
  2 * * * * 2
    3 * * * 3
      4 * * 4
        5 * 5
          6 6
            7
```